# How do i load a Chrome extension when manifest.json is in a subfolder (app) instead of main folder

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I cloned an extension from github trying to modify a shortcut to work for me.
[The extension](https://github.com/pc035860/yt-timetag)

But when I load the extension from the "app folder" (the one contain manifest.json) chrome gives back several errors

- Unrecognized manifest key 'browser_specific_settings'.
- Manifest version 2 is deprecated, and support will be removed in 2024.
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

And I believe this is because I didnt figure out the way to tell Google Chrome how to load the extension from the main folder.

Correct me if i'm wrong because I don't have any knowledge about building a Chrome extension, just trying to get the shortcuts to work.

Comment: You must build this extension and then load the result into the browser. Install nodejs, then run something like `npm i && npm run dist` in the directory. Why don't you [modify the extension from the web store](/a/16688027)?

Comment: I'll try both now

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, i had some problems with versions and dependency tree thing with "npm i" but the other solution u mentioned
"Chrome extension source viewer" worked. Its all good now.